Query Workday for active projects with SOAP API
I have been working on a accessing our Workday projects via the SOAP API. I have not figured out how to get only active projects. I've tried a few different things, as evidenced by the commented out sections in the Project_Status_Reference below.
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
         <bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>true</bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>
      </bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <bsvc:Get_Projects_Request xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc" bsvc:version="">
        
        <bsvc:Request_Criteria>
            <!--<bsvc:End_Date_On_or_After>2024-08-21</bsvc:End_Date_On_or_After>-->
            <bsvc:Project_Status_Reference>
            
                <!--<bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Document_Status_ID">Proposed</bsvc:ID>-->
                <!-- <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="wid">Active - Expenses Only</bsvc:ID>-->
                <!--<bsvc:ID bsvc:type="WID">975e0cfc6de60106b67f47ed71106042</bsvc:ID> -->
                <!--active -->
                <!--<bsvc:ID bsvc:type="WID">975E0CFC6DE60106B67F47ED71106042</bsvc:ID>-->
                <!-- Active -->
                <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Document_Status_ID">ACTIVE</bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Project_Status_Reference>
        </bsvc:Request_Criteria>
        <bsvc:Response_Filter>
            <bsvc:Page></bsvc:Page>
        </bsvc:Response_Filter>
    </bsvc:Get_Projects_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

The documentation requires either a WID or Document_Status_ID for the type, which I don't get because I'm trying to retrieve projects, not documents. When I use <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Document_Status_ID">ACTIVE</bsvc:ID>, no projects are returned.  Using the WID, I get the following error
SOAP-ENV:Client.validationErrorValidation error occurred. Invalid instance 13572$1 for
 | Project_Statuses_for_Find_Projects_Selected--IS (15$65209)

When using anyhting like Proposed, Active - Expenses Only or ACTIVE_EXPENSES_ONLY, I get an error that value is invalid
SOAP-ENV:Client.validationErrorValidation error occurred. Invalid ID value.  'ACTIVE_TIME_ONLY' is not a valid ID   
 | value for type = 'Document_Status_ID'Invalid ID value.

What do I need to do to retrieve projects that are Proposed, Active, Active - Expenses Only and Active - Time Only?

You may be having a schema issue.  Is the URI of namespace valid? xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc"

this works if I leave Project_status_reference  empty or omit the element all together.

Project _status is using the namespace bsvc that is why it works when you comment out the section.  There is a schema check that is failing and cannot tell what is wrong without a valid URI for the namespace bscv.

From the documentation
<bsvc:Get_Projects_Request xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc" bsvc:version="string">
and
`
<bsvc:Project_Status_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="string">

<bsvc:ID bsvc:type="string">string</bsvc:ID>
</bsvc:Project_Status_Reference>`

Also, if I uncomment the end date element, that filter works as well.
<bsvc:End_Date_On_or_After>2024-08-21</bsvc:End_Date_On_or_After>

Workday wants 2024-08-21T00:00:00

If you run it wide open, do you get projects that are in active status? Or do you see active projects in Workday?

Yes, wide open I get back all projects. I also can filter based on start and end dates, just can't get the project status filter to work.

Have you logged a ticket in Workday Customer Center about it or asked on Community?

Someone is seeing everything come through as Approved. Are you seeing Different statuses come through when you run it wide open? https://collaborate.workday.com/t5/Platform-Product-Extensions/Soap-API-Get-Project-Project-Status/td-p/802712
